# How to call subclass constructor only in inheritence

Tags: c#, oop

Is there any possibility in inheritance in c# so that we can have subclass constructor call only without calling base class constructor as a default base class constructor calls firstly

Comment: Are we talking about Java or C# ?

Comment: Explain how that would work. What would happen with unitialized base class fields?

Comment: we are talking about c# is there any possibility?

Comment: The answer is no, but I suspect you're trying to do something specific, like having the subclass constructor run before the base class constructor?  Please explain what your _problem_ is rather than asking is a particular _solution_ is possible.

Answer (score 2):

A subclass constructor will always call a superclass constructor: either the default superclass constructor or a (maybe parametrized) superclass constructor, which can be chosen by you, when you declare your subclass constructor.